# Can't update mysql table with insert

Tags: mysql

I have an identic bunch of tables in the same base, created with:

```
CREATE TABLE $current_date (
  call_state varchar(10),
  call_rate smallint(6), 
  ip-address varchar(15), 
  comment varchar(70)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Once a day the fresh one is filled with values, except 'comment' field. The rule for filling up the mentioned field is.

```
INSERT INTO $current_date (comment)
SELECT comment FROM $yesterday_date WHERE call_state='-';
-- ('call_state' may be + or - or +-)
```

MySQL Response is:

> Query OK, 17 rows affected (0.02 sec)
>   Records: 17  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

But in fact there no any changes in `$current_date` table - all the comment cells are still `NULL`.
Can anybody point the way me to get the column filled?

Comment: to update a value, it's a fine idea to use UPDATE, not INSERT

Comment: How do you determine which rows of the $current_date table should have their comments updated? Is there a relationship between the rows in $yesterday_date and $current_date?

Comment: What should I do is update each $current_date.comment with the  $yesterday_table.comment (both rows have identical similar values) where $current_date.comment is '-'.

Answer (score 0):

**INSERT**
The command `INSERT` is used to add new rows into a table. If you get the response "Query OK, 17 rows affected" than none of the previous existing rows did change, but the number of rows did increase by 17.

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES(value1, value2);
```

---

**UPDATE**
If you want to update existing rows use the command `UPDATE`. "UPDATE" does not add any rows. It changes the content of existing rows.

```
UPDATE table SET column1=value1, column2=value2 WHERE column3=value3;
```